# Dynamic VirtualHost w/ Include Directive

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm trying to think of an apache configuration based on the one from the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html#simple) where each virtualhost is essentially the same, but I wan't to add an include directive pointing to a config file to differentiate each one, allowing differences in config, without using an htaccess file.

```
# get the server name from the Host: header
UseCanonicalName Off

# this log format can be split per-virtual-host based on the first field
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog logs/access_log vcommon

# include the server name in the filenames used to satisfy requests
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%0/docs
VirtualScriptAlias /www/hosts/%0/cgi-bin
```

But I don't suppose I can add `Include /www/hosts/conf/%0.conf` or something similar?

Is there any standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include **one** file in which you can, if needed, define Virtualhost container for every modified from default settings virthost. It's not standard, but *widely used practice*.

I use it and find more easy to maintain 1 file than (rather) long set

Comment: Sounds good. Does each VirtualHost container you specify in that file inherit from the default, or would you have to specify the `DocumentRoot`, `ServerName`, etc.. again?

Comment: I write *all explicitly*, can't recall reasons for "why" and add additional definitions